# C++: Linking files with GCC compiler

Tags: c++, linker, declaration, undefined-reference

I have three files : myh.h; my.cpp; use.cpp. Here are the contents of the files:

**myh.h**

```
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

**my.cpp**

```
#include "myh.h"
#include <iostream>
void print_foo()
{
    std::cout<<foo<<std::endl;
}
void print(int i)
{
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

**use.cpp**

```
#include "myh.h"
int main()
{
    foo=7;
    print_foo();
    print(99);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC spews out the following error:

```
my.o:my.cpp:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `foo'
use.o:use.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I compile the files using the -c command and it doesn't give errors. I link using the following command:

```
g++ -o final my.o use.o
```

What is the problem here, I read other topics with similar problems, and the case here is just strange .....

For the curious this is an exercise drill from Stroustrup's book Programming principles of using C++

**Edit:** I did as dasblinkenlight said, and in use.cpp I added an int in front of foo (so now foo is defined), but I still get this error:

```
my.o:my.cpp:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which tells me that it is not defined in my.cpp also? If I have to define it everywhere what is the point of including it in the header file, or how should this be approached more appropriately?

Comment: @mcalex it doesn't matter what the name is, as long as it is the same

Comment: @lekroif: Actually, if you need to link with Sun CC and use its funny external template mechanism, you distinctly want to have different base names for the header and implementation if there is a template declared in the header (otherwise it will kind of include the implementation file whenever the template is used).

Comment: @Dietmar I suspected that some compilers might behave like that and that is why I have named the header myh.h In the original exercise the instructions were to name it my.h (same as the cpp file).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get a linker error because you *declared* `foo`, but you never *defined* it.

`extern int foo` is only a declaration; it does not cause allocation of memory for the `foo` variable, only promises that you will do it at some other place. To fix it, you need to add this line to one of the cpp files, like this:

```
#include "myh.h"
int foo;
int main()
{
    foo=7;
    print_foo();
    print(99);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, logical, I defined foo in the use.cpp by adding "int" in front of it. I get one error less, but I still have linking errors: 
my.o:my.cpp:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Why? If I define it in every file what is the point of including it then...

Comment: @lekroif I edited the answer to show where to define `foo` (it needs to be in the global, i.e. the outermost scope). I tried this locally, and everything worked fine.

Comment: Yes, thanks!!!I will do a bit more reading to figure out the source of my confusion.

Comment: This has got to be a dupe. I see a question like this asked at least once a month.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `foo` is declared but not defined. You need to define `foo` in exactly one of the translation units, e.g.:

```
int foo = 0;
```